# Material Dialog Close on mouseleave (angular material)

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

I created a dialog using Angular Material
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview
I open it here `<td *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" on-mouseover='openDialog(item)' on-mouseleave='closeDialog()' >`
Where in component I have definition of those functions:

```
openDialog(item:Item) {
this.dialog.open(ItemDialog,{
  data: {
    someData: item.data
 })
}
```

And

```
  closeDialog(){
    console.log("close");
    this.dialog.closeAll;

  }
```

This is my dialog definition:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'item-dialog.html',
})
export class ItemDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

ngOnInit() {
}
```

When I hover mouse over the item, the dialog pops up. However when I leave it, it does not dissapear (I have to click outside the button to make it vanish.)
What is more, console.log appears when I hover mouse (At the same time as dialog appears)
I really do not know what happens. I just wanted to have a popup which appears and disappears when hovering something.

Comment: Is it a real dialog with a backdrop and blocking the UI ? If so, that's a terrible practice ...

Comment: So what would you recommend? I need a bigger popup with posibility to show small image + variables. Tooltip can show only String

Comment: The [CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) is made for that.  [Several online tutorials](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/20/custom-overlays-with-angulars-cdk.html) explain how to implement it too.

Comment: Looks great. It also shows that I can set timeout and so on.
But I cannot see the possibility to directly close dialog (So I could make a mouseover function)

Comment: You have to use the reference of the modal, which has a `close` function.

Comment: A pitty it is a comment, as I would mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you but I didn't really answered your question there. Make an answer on your own and accept it, it's still some reputation that you earn !

Comment: And if you absolutely want to return the favor, simply upvote one of my answers on my profile !

Answer (score 2):

it seems like your `mouseover` and `mouseleave` triggers are in the list of `items`, however, Angular Material dialog, once open, will also open an overlay layer, something like:

```
<div class"cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>
```

Which has a `z-indez` of `1000` and probably overlaps your items, so the `mouseleave` wont't be triggered, since there is another DOM element on top of the item now.

For what you want, I suggest looking into tooltips or popovers (which usually are relative positioned to the element), instead of dialogs. Otherwise, everytime you open a dialog on top of your item element, it will not close automatically on mouse leave.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgot to add `()` on the `closeAll` method. So you need to use:

```
closeDialog(){
  console.log("close");
  this.dialog.closeAll();
}
```

or add reference to the opened dialog:

```
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef;

openDialog(item:Item) {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ItemDialog,{
    data: {
      someData: item.data
  });
}
```

and then close it using:

```
closeDialog(){
  console.log("close");
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```