# Close Modal using mouseleave

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I developed a modal using bootstrap. Is there a way to close the modal using the mouseleave?

thank you

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5sikx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<button (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="onmouseleave($event)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it a bit better anyway, I'm trying to trigger the close on mouseleave now.

I looked at the answer given and the documentation.

The documentation says: "Modals use position: fixed, which can sometimes be a bit particular about its rendering. Whenever possible, place your modal HTML in a top-level position to avoid potential interference from other elements."

So I added the position: fixed to the .modal class in the .css file

I'm still looking at the close on mouseleave for you but also, just incase the docs also say: "Clicking on the modal “backdrop” will automatically close the modal." Which is the way I've done it in the added stackblitz, the flickering has stopped anyway.

source: [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#how-it-works)

Stackblitz: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6lpsf)

This answer from 8 months ago may be helpful too: [Closing Angular on mouseover - recommended another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291254/material-dialog-close-on-mouseleave-angular-material)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !!

Comment: Sooo glad I could help! <3

Answer (score 0):

See [bootstrap modals documentatio](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#how-it-works)n for know how it works

```
onmouseleave(event: any): void {
  event.target.click();
}
```

You may need use [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

Comment: Isn't there a more consistent way to solve this? is that whenever I move with the mouse the modal constantly opens and closes